# how to create a nodeJS module with expressJS

Tags: node.js, function, api, express, module

I'm making a nodeJS module, and I want to use expressJS as a framework for it.
I'm trying to see, how I could go by, including a function inside and app.get(); and call it via another file, such as the actual app.

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    exports.type = function (text) {
        console.log(req.ip);
        console.log(text);
    }
});
```

now when I use this, and i call it on the actual app like:

```
var web = require("directory_to_file");
var express = require("express");
var app = express();
var http = require("http").Server(app);
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    web.type("Hello, world");
});
http.listen(10022, function () {
    console.log("server is up");
});
```

I get an error:

```
TypeError: Property 'type' of object #<Object> is not a function
```

anyone know a way to make it so I can call the function?

Answer (score 3):

There are generally two things you want to export as a module - an API and a Middleware.  The classic example of middleware is an authentication module.  To do the middleware, just export the middleware.  I tend to do a little more than that so I can configure the middleware later.  Something along the lines of this:

```
module.exports = exports = function(config) {
  // Do something with config here

  return function(req, res, next) {
    // your middleware here
  };
};
```

You can then use your middleware in your main program like this:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    mymodule = require('./mymodule');

var config = {}; // replace with whatever config you need

app.use(mymodule(config));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

To implement an API, you will create a Router object, then attach your routes to the Router object.  You can then "mount" your router in your main program.  For example, you could have a file called 'myroutes.js' with the following contents:

```
var express = require('express'),
    myroutes = express.Router();

myroutes.get('/foo', (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).type('application/json').send({ myparam: 'foo' });
});

module.exports = exports = myroutes;
```

Have the following in your main program:

```
var app = require('express')(),
    myroutes = require('./myroutes');

app.use('/api', require('./myroutes'));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Here, in 'myroutes.js', I'm defining a sub-route of /foo and then in the main program, I'm mounting that on /api - so I would access /api/foo to access that API.

Comment: Is this practice still relevant today for Express in 2021? Or are there other considerations...?

Comment: Yes - see http://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Answer (score 1):

In your `directory_to_file` you are only exporting on `app.get('/')` which will never be called.

You could add in your `directory_to_file` the following code

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/', function(req, server) {
    console.log(req.ip);
});

module.exports = router;
```

And in your main file you could use `app.use('/', web)`

A short explanation:
You are creating a new express app / config in your `directory_to_file` file which won't be launched or used. So your app.get event won't be fired once.

That's why `web.type` is not a function. You are not exporting anything.
Use the way I provided. This is a commonly used method.

You could call the code I provided a "route". Create multiple routes / route files and include them in your main method.

Comment: this works but what if I want to include extra parameters in my function?

Comment: I edited the code above, would you know how to get that working?

Comment: Could you add that you parse your parameter? Might depend on what that parameter is.

Comment: the parameter is a string.

Comment: sorry was that what you where asking?

Comment: Yes but what is the string for? You could hardcore it? You could add a config file and add the string in there.I am not sure about the usage and therefore not sure how to implent it.

Comment: ah I see what you are asking sorry. I do a poor job at explaining myself. I want to be able to define what that string is from the actual app. like web.type("Hello, world"); and it prints out Hello world into the console

Comment: does that help explain it better?

Comment: More or less, yes. But what is the purpose behind to parse it as a parameter?

Comment: I guess just as insight. so I can grasp the knowledge of it better probably.

Answer (score 0):

Your code just looks confused. If I understand you correctly, what you are really trying to do (at least in Node/express terminology) is write your own [middleware](http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html).

Express is designed with this in mind and it's pretty straightforward e.g.

**ipLogger.js**

```
module.exports = function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.ip);
    next();
}
```

**app.js**

```
var http = require("http")
  , express = require("express");
  , app = express()
  , server = http.Server(app)
  , ipLogger = require("./ipLogger.js");

app.use(ipLogger()); // log IP of all requests
// handle routes

server.listen(10022, function() {
    console.log("server is up");
});
```